# JQuery separate child element from parent

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Basically I have an element which when clicked causes another element to slideToggle. However what I am after is another element, say an image, inside the main parent element that when that is clicked it does not fire off the slideToggle event and can be used to fire another event...

A simplified version of my code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/s3d5D/6/

..the blue box being a substitute for the image.

Markup:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="section"><div class="image"></div></div>
    <div class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.hidden').hide();
$(document).on('click', '.section', function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.hidden:first').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `target` property of event arguments object contains the element that was really clicked. You can compare it to `this` (which will contain the related `.section` element) and find out whether it was the `.section` that was clicked, or something else:

```
$(document).on('click', '.section', function(e){
    if (e.target == this) {
        $(this).nextAll('.hidden:first').slideToggle(500);
    }
});
```

I've also forked your fiddle to illustrate this approach [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/keTU8/).

Comment: This solution is neat and implements well into what I am trying to achieve. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can [stop the propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) of the event at the child element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.image', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/s3d5D/7/). Notice in the fiddle that I have chained your existing `on` call with the above, so you don't have to create more than one jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

I've used more or less the same approach as [James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11334728/82548), in that I've used `event.stopPropagation()`, but I've chosen, instead, to evaluate the target of the `click` event within the `on()` method, rather than chaining two, or potentially more, calls to `on()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.section, .image', function() {
    var thisClass = $(this).is('.section') ? 'section' : 'image';
    if (thisClass == 'section') {
        $(this).nextAll('.hidden:first').slideToggle(500);
    }
    else if (thisClass == 'image') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s3d5D/8/).

Comment: +1, I can never decide which form I prefer out of this or that of my answer.

Comment: @James: I must confess that I tend to go back and forth between the two options, too. I should, really, test it to see where the overheads/bottlenecks lie, but I've never really found the time to make the effort... =/

Comment: @JamesAllardice yours will perform much faster. jQuery cannot optimize `.section, .image` and evaluating that selector against multiple elements each time click happens is gonna be extremely slow in IE7.

Comment: Further to my original comment, @Esailija, do you have any metrics to back that up? (Purely out of curiosity, since I really don't want to have to test for myself...yep; I'm just being lazy.)

Comment: @DavidThomas if your selector matches this regex `var rquickIs = /^(\w*)(?:#([\w\-]+))?(?:\.([\w\-]+))?$/` it's gonna skip CSS selector engine entirely (which in ie7 is even worse because it means using sizzle and not native)

Comment: Run this jsfiddle in IE7 http://jsfiddle.net/PAjqU/ and move your mouse circularly as fast as possible (just try to hit the cap). Then change the selector to `".test"` and do the same (as long as it matches the `rquickIs`). The quick selector caps at 964 events per s and the non-quick selector caps at 860 events per s for me. The difference is as small as possible because the event target always instantly matches the delegation criteria. The optimized selector would get ahead more if that wasn't the case.

Comment: These comments are great - not tested it in IE7 etc as yet but now aware of the possible issues. Thanks All